# Strange C# Syntax bug - one line is not considered a statement?

Tags: c#, syntax

I have two lines of C# from a sample I'm converting. One is fine, the other however produces an error in VS2012, Sharpdevelop and an online convertor.

Can anyone clear up why the first line is no good but the second line is just fine? A trivial mystery that I can't seem to clarify for myself! :). The first line is NOT a statement according to VS.

```
double xx = x * Math.Cos(a) – this.y * Math.Sin(a);

double yy = y * Math.Sin(a) + this.y * Math.Cos(a);
```

I'd be grateful for any clarity offered!

Comment: Are you going to make us guess what the error is?

Comment: You may want to add a little more context to this: both declarations appear fine in isolation, so the error is related to what's around your statements, not in the code itself.

Comment: Hi Eric it's a daft example I was converting from C# to vb in order to add to a document. There isn't much additional context. Looks like someone has the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [**hyphen minus**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) character, not an [**en dash**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

In the first statement you used the `–` character whereas you should have used `-`:

```
double xx = x * Math.Cos(a) - this.y * Math.Sin(a);
```

Notice the difference with:

```
double xx = x * Math.Cos(a) – this.y * Math.Sin(a);
```

I guess some copy-paste from a website or a Word document got wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The thing that looks like a minus sign (–) is actually an en dash - it should be a plain hyphen.